# onclicklistener on Android 4.0

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with onclicklistener from a button control defined on a child object. This event seems to never get fired. The ontouchlistener seems to be working. Has anyone experienced this problem with Android 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    ...
    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);
    ...
}
```

or

xml:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/butHello" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Поздороваться" 
    android:onClick="butHello_Click"></Button>
```

code:

```
public void butHello_Click(View v){
    edtext.setText("Здравствуй, друг");
}
```

//copied from http://habrahabr.ru/post/114580/

Answer (score 0):

click may use like

```
    Button  btnclick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnclick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // do here as require

            }
        });

}
```